# How to use page transitions with Expression Engine

Tags: conditionals, jquery

I'm trying to use page transitions using smoothstate.js (http://miguel-perez.github.io/smoothState.js/).

What this appears to do is to load the destination of a link in the background when the link is hovered rather than clicked, meaning when it is actually clicked the content is already loaded and can be presented with a smooth transition.

The challenge I'm finding is that I often use an {if segment_3 != ''} type conditional to use one template to show both a listings AND a detail page and avoid having to create an extra template and add an extra segment to my URL. Something like this...

```
{if segment_3 == ''}

    Listings page to go here...

{if:elseif segment_3 != ''}

    Detail page to go here...

{/if}
```

This seems to cause problems and not load the content on these detail pages correctly. I can only assume this is because when the content is loaded, the URL hasn't changed yet, meaning the EE conditional still comes out as false rather than positive.

Any ideas on how to get around this would be massively helpful and appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Tom

Comment: This plugin works as ajax loader with cache +  changed page url after loading (window.location). In any case, the data is loaded by specific url, not what you see in the current moment and if you choose correct segment - conditional must work. So is nothing about ee as is. Open chrome inspector on tab Network and check what url you requested.

Answer (score 1):

This is a completely front-end issue, as Max Lazar said. There is no way EE template conditionals have anything to do with browser presentation frameworks, only generated content and structure. If you are ajaxing some content, and your URL to the page you want ajaxed is correct, ie:

```
/products/product_category/
```

vs

```
/products/product_category/product_one
```

that template will be parsed exactly as it would be without this front-end framework.

If you can test and give us more details about your templates **without** using this front-end framework, we might be able to help you find a problem with your templates that is completely separate from implementing the framework.

**Update**

After looking at the two page examples, **they are binary equals**. Your issue here comes down to browser behavior with respect to loading stylesheet rules and painting them appropriately. I've run into this thing before; sadly there is no easy or direct solution. I would initially try reloading the stylesheet rules to see if you can get a browser repaint:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2024486/is-there-an-easy-way-to-reload-css-without-reloading-the-page

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13721183/reload-css-stylesheets-with-javascript

http://ajaxian.com/archives/browser-reflows-how-do-they-affect-performance

But I can foresee that getting messy, unless you basically write a jQuery plugin (or vanialla JavaScript library) triggered by a smoothState.js callback of some kind. Either way, this is browser behavior in regards to the particular structure and stylesheet rules of your website. Browsers do not paint the same after load, I believe.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts guys. It's a strange one then if as you say the presentation framework doesn't effect back-end loading.

Comment: As an example, here's a listings page with smoothstate in place (http://dev.evolvewebsites.co/examples). If you hover on one of the websites you should see the detail page loaded in the console before you click. The trouble is that when you do click the page doesn't display correctly. Here's how the page should display (http://dev.evolvewebsites.co/examples/table-magic-website) but if you try to access that page from the listings page it doesn't load correctly (i.e. incorrect page height and no images). If you need any more info just let me know.

Comment: Thanks for providing an example! I (and likely Blatant) will take a look in a few hours. I might need more info, I'll let you know.

Comment: thanks for looking into this. I'm a little confused by your answer I'm afraid, not something I've come across before. Could you explain what you mean by 'they are binary equals' and why that would mean styles for the detail page aren't loading please?

Comment: Basically, when your browser loads a web page, it loads the DOM structure and applies styling as the style rules load. This causes a specific order of rule application. If you are to asynchronously change the entire DOM structure of your page, the style rules end up not getting painted in the same order. Often this is because you have JavaScripts that add additional style rules when the page loads. However, this library may not be triggering an on-load event. It's annoyingly complex to try and recreate a page load event without simply asking the browser to load a new page.

Comment: By binary equals, I mean the separate page load and the asynchronous page load are exactly the same; the library is doing what it says it does. Like I said, trying to force a reload/repaint of your style rules could work. You might also just need to force some style rules with a callback from the front end library your using. I wish I could do more for you; this issue is interesting and definitely requires a good developer to suss out, and I don't have time (gotta go to work!).

Comment: I really appreciate your help on this one. I've just removed Smooth State and instead am trying out Animsition (https://github.com/blivesta/animsition). I've only applied to the examples section for now (http://dev.evolvewebsites.co/examples) and strangely it appears to be working for the links within the page (i.e. click on the screenshots to view an example then click the back link to return) but the links in the header now appear to all be linking to '/undefined'. Do you think this could be caused by the fact that the navigation is an embed and something to do with load order there?

Comment: A quick page at the docs for Animsition shows that you need to have this class on your links: *class="animsition-link"*. The header links don't appear to have that value set, so try that. Also, this particular framework is **not** asynchronously loading, so when you click a link, the browser does a full page load. This is probably why this framework is working for your website (actual page loads, and not simulated but AJAXed content).

Comment: That's really helpful, thanks. Apologies for wasting time on header links, I'd placed the class on the li element rather than the link itself. Surely I can't be the first to encounter this issue with Smoothstate, any ideas on routes to a solution?